# How open one screen if a new user registered successfully, and other when existing user logged in succesfully using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I'm working on Log In and Sign Up pages using Firebase Auth by email&password.

What is done successfully:

If the session (login or sign up) isn't **nil**, then user goes to a Welcome Back  View.

The question is next:

I don't want a new user to go to **"Welcome Back "** View, instead, I want him after pressing "Sign Up" button (is session isn't **nil** to go to a new View - "Upload Your Photo View"

My Session Store Class (@ObservableObject):

```
 @Published var session: User? {didSet{self.didChange.send(self)}}
 var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
let currentuser = Auth.auth().currentUser




func listen(){
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({(auth, user) in
        if let user = user{
            self.session = User(uid: user.uid, email: user.email)
        } else {
            self.session = nil
        }

    })
}

func signUp(email: String, password: String, fullname: String, username: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password,  completion: handler)


}

func signIn(email: String, password: String, handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){ (res,err) in
        if err != nil{
            return
        }

    }
```

}

```
func signOut(){
    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.session = nil
    }catch{
        print("Error signing out")
    }
}

func unbind() {
    if let handle = handle {
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
}

deinit {
    unbind()
}

func addUsername(username: String){
    session?.username = username
}
func addFullname(fullname: String){
    session?.fullname = fullname
}


class User:ObservableObject{

var uid: String
var email: String?
var username: String?
var fullname: String?

    init(uid:String, email:String?){

    self.uid = uid
    self.email = email

}

}}
```

My Content View Looks like that :

Group{
                if (session.session != nil){

```
                Button(action: {
                    try! Auth.auth().signOut()
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
                }){
                    Text("Log out")
                }
                ExploreView()

            }else{

                        AuthView()

            }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
```

Comment: Hi Maksym, can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Regarding your `SessionStore`: you don't need to use `PassthroughSubject` directly - it's good enough to implement `ObservableObject` and tag any property you want to observe using `@Published`. Check out https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part3/ for a Firebase Auth implementation with Sign in with Apple for some best practices for SwiftUI and Firebase.

Comment: Hey, Peter! Appreciate your answer! My goal is to show a new user and an old user different views. But now I can show them only one screen if they are logged in.

Comment: To make an old user go to home page (if logged in) and a new (just registered user) go to add a photo screen.  I just don't know how to separate them to achieve it.

Comment: Have you considered using `lastSignInDate` or `creationDate`? See the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/UserMetadata#/c:objc(cs)FIRUserMetadata(py)creationDate

Comment: Thank you, not yet, but will try!

Comment: Sounds like an answer @PeterFriese :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be a two way binding which just triggers if signUp was successful (so it is the first login ever in that moment).

Edit to your comment: In signUp-func you set a variable to "true" when signUp was successful and PhotoUploadView will pop up.

Add a variable in class User (which can be used then in your variable session):

```
    @Published var firstLogin = false
```

Change firstLogin after successful signup in signUp-func:

```
session.firstLogin = true
```

Use something like this in ContentView:

```
//.....
else{
if session.firstLogin {
         PhotoUploadView()
        }
```

Set session.firstLogin to false afterwards, whenever you are done in PhotoUploadView.

Comment: Hi, @Kuhlemann! Really appreciate your answer! I've uploaded my ContentView code just now.

Comment: See my updated answer to get an approach of what to do.

Comment: Been trying to solve them, but each time appear only more. These are the errors I received in ContentView: 1) Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Subject>' to expected condition type 'Bool'   2)Value of type 'SessionStore' has no dynamic member 'secondLogin' using key path from root type 'SessionStore'   3) Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'EnvironmentObject<SessionStore>.Wrapper'

Comment: Made 2 variables : firstLogin - for sign up and secondLogin - for log in. Every time i try to change the ***false*** status to true in sign up function, this error appears (Value of type 'SessionStore.User' has no member 'firstLogin')

Comment: Sorry but, these are further questions not directly related to your original question. I can't solve this with just your comments and with only getting a little piece of code (or no new code in this case). But another hint: You don't need a secondLogin-variable, because if firstLogin is false, then per definition its a login >= 2nd login. If my answer helped anyway I would appreciate if you mark it as accepted and upvote it.

Comment: Okey, got it. Appreciate your help!